# Cheer her on or cheer on her?

Tags: grammaticality, phrasal-verbs

Which of these sentences is correct?

1. > Becky's parents cheer her on during her matches.
2. > Becky's parents cheer on during her matches.
3. > Becky's parents cheer on her during her matches.

The last one sounds weird to me.
Thanks!

Comment: The third sentence is grammatical and means something, but probably not what you intend it to mean. It means that Becky’s parents cheer during Becky’s matches, but they do so while sitting on top of poor Becky. That is, ‘on’ has its literal meaning if you place it before Becky like this.

Comment: _Cheer on_ is not a phrasal verb. Though it appears in a number of idiomatic verb phrases, _on_ does not occur as a particle in phrasal verbs with Particle Shift. _I cheered him on,_ but not *_I cheered on him_; _She told on me,_ but not *_She told me on._

Comment: @JohnLawler I don’t quite follow your comment there. The fact that _on_ is a particle and that the construction does take particle shifting surely means that _cheer on_ **is** a phrasal verb, just not a prepositional phrasal verb. “_On_ does not occur as a particle in phrasal verbs with Particle Shift” seems like quite the opposite of observable fact to me.

Comment: @Janus: The stars indicate that transitive _cheer on_ and _tell on_ do not undergo particle shift. They're certainly idiomatic and they certainly are composed of `Verb` + _on_, but I wouldn't call them phrasal verbs (I'd also exclude _look at_ for the same reason).

Comment: @JohnLawler But _cheer on_ does undergo particle shifting. “They cheered on their daughter” -> “They cheered her on”, as opposed to “She told on her neighbour” -> “She told on him”. If that’s not what you call particle shifting, then what do you use that term to mean?

Comment: @Janus: Ah, I see. *_They cheered on their daughter_ is ungrammatical for me; at best, it sounds like they did something unpleasant all over her, like vomiting or sneezing. I can't get it with stressed _on_, which would be required for a phrasal verb. So, lexicons differ and the language moves on. My lexicon is  older than most people's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the idiom **cheer on**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cheer) and to **cheer on**, a phrasal verb. [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cheer-on)

> To support or encourage someone or something, often vocally. A noun or
>   pronoun can be used between "cheer" and "on."

Becky's parents cheer her on during her matches. / correct

Becky's parents cheer on during her matches. / correct (phrasal verb to **cheer on**).

Becky's parents cheer on her during her matches. / incorrect

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is almost correct (I removed the unnecessary second "her")

> Becky's parents cheer her on during matches.

The second sentence should be (removing "on")

> Becky's parents cheer during her matches.

The third sentence is wrong, you "cheer someone on", not "cheer on someone".

Comment: Should be pointed out that there’s nothing wrong with the second _you_ in the first example. It may not be necessary, but it sounds more natural to me with it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think you mean "there's nothing wrong with the second *her*."  And I agree.

Comment: @Juhasz Er, yes, _her_. Mustn’t type on phone whilst trying to have a spoken conversation at the same time.